# Keep Object as Object after filtering

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

That is my datastructure

```
const data = Immutable.fromJS({
        1: {
            foo: 'bar'
            ...
        },
        2: {
            foo: 'foo'
            ...
        },
        3: {
            foo: 'foobar'
            ...
        },
    },
});
```

I want to filter the data and I need my `filteredData` to be of exactly the same type - `Immutable Object`. When I run

```
const filtered = data.get('data').valueSeq().filter(obj => {
    ...
    return obj;
});
```

I get this `[{}, {}, {}, ...]`.

I need it to be like this (as the input data) `{1: {...}, 2: {...}, 3: {...}}`. What is the correct `filter` function for this so that the return type is already a `Map` and not an `Array`. Or is there nothing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filtering your object is still an ImmutableObject (see example)

```js
const data = Immutable.fromJS({
    data: {
        1: {
            foo: 'bar'
        },
        2: {
            foo: 'foo'
        },
        3: {
            foo: 'foobar'
        },
    },
    kittens: {}
});

const res = data.get('data').filter(obj=>obj.get('foo') === 'bar');
console.log(res);

//still immutable object
console.log(res.get('1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I also thought that after I read it in [their specifications](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts#L585) but you were a lot faster ^_^

Answer (score 1):

My proposition retaining original data structure:

```js
const data = Immutable.fromJS({
    data: {
        1: {
            foo: 'bar'
        },
        2: {
            foo: 'foo'
        },
        3: {
            foo: 'foobar'
        },
    },
});

const filtered = data.updateIn(
  ['data'],
  v => v.filter(obj=>obj.get('foo') === 'bar'));
  
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.valueSeq()`. That is what is converting object to array